# Given (id <MyDelegate>)delegate, can you tell what kind of class delegate is?

Tags: objective-c

When passing a delegate to MyClass like this,

```
- (MyClass *)initWithDelegate:(id <MyDelegate>)delegate {..}
```

is it somehow possible to tell what kind of class my delegate is? Being defined as id, delegate doesn't seem to respond to any method calls like class, description, respondsToSelector etc.

I'd like to be able to track who is calling MyClass!

Thanks in advance!

/Christian

Comment: As @sch points out, you may want to put a debug statement checking to see if the delegate is `nil` or not.  `NSLog(@"is nil:%i", delegate == nil);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call `[delegate class];` to get the class of the `delegate`.

If `delegate` doesn't respond to that, that means it is `nil`.

**Edit**

Now that you mention that you get compiler errors, then your delegate doesn't conform to the protocol `NSObject`. So the compiler doesn't recognize it as an `NSObject`. You should modify the declaration of your protocol `MyDelegate` to the following:

```
@protocol MyDelegate <NSObject>

// ...

@end
```

Comment: Sorry, but if I try calling [delegate class] my code will not compile due to "no known instance method for selector 'class'".

Comment: Yes, indeed! Wasn't aware you explicitly need to specify the protocol as NSObject. Now I can get the information from my delegate I'm looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In the case when you can't modify the protocol itself, you could simply write:

```
- (MyClass*) initWithDelegate:(id<NSObject, MyDelegate>)delegate {..}
```

Then the 'class' property will be available. You can replace NSObject (or add additional protocols) to support (and thus require the argument to be of) other types. For example:

```
- (MyClass*) initWithDelegate:(id<NSObject, NSCoding, MyDelegate>)delegate {..}
```